# mysqli_real_escape_string returns empty inside function

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a function which has to **filter the data** passed into a `$_GET` variable. It recently worked, but I began working with mysqli and now it's not anymore. Echoing my `$data` everytime it went through a PHP function gave the result that the `mysqli_real_escape_string` causing the variable `$data` **to return empty**. But what am I doing wrong here.

My function which should filter the `$_GET` variables, but the `mysqli_real_escape_string` **returns an empty variable..**

```
    function filter($data) {
            global $link;
            $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data);    
            return $data;
        }
```

A loop in order to run all `$_GET` variables trough the filter.

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

The connection with the database (the connection does work): (`$link`)

```
$link=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: `$link` is not available inside the function due to [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I am using `global $link;` and still not working. Also tried `$GLOBALS['link'];` but says index link is unkown...

Comment: What reason using `globals` here? What do you follow? Please,explain this approach.

Comment: As I explained `mysqli_real_escape_string` is returning an empty variable. I previously used `mysql_real_...` and added the `$link` variable. I can't use $link inside a function if it is not global.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function to include `$link` and pass it by reference if you like:

```
function filter($data, &$link) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data);    
    return $data;
}
```